# Directive Non-Assignable Expression, when project is built with grunt (yeoman settings)

Tags: angularjs

I got this error when I use my directive:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '' used with directive 'profileModifier' is non-assignable!
```

However, the error only occurs when my project is built with grunt. It works in devmode.

My directive:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .directive('profileModifier', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'template/profile-modifier/profile-modifier.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        title: '=',
        enabled: '=',
        available: '=',
        show: '=',
        values: '=',
        columnTitleOne: '=',
        columnTitleTwo: '=',
        columnPropertyKeyOne: '=',
        columnPropertyKeyTwo: '=',
        uploadFn: '='
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.toggleOnOff = function(val){
          scope.enabled = val;
          if(!val){
            scope.show = false;
          }
        };

        scope.toggleShow = function(){
          scope.show = !scope.show;
        }

      }
    };
  });
```

Markup:

```
<profile-modifier
    title="'Lutningsprofil'"
    enabled="selectedProfile.value.slope.enabled"
    available="selectedProfile.value.slope.available"
    show="selectedProfile.value.slope.show"
    values="selectedProfile.value.slope.values"
    column-title-one="'KM'"
    column-title-two="'Lutning (‰)'"
    column-property-key-one="'distance'"
    column-property-key-two="'slope'"
    upload-fn="openUploadModalSlope">
</profile-modifier>
```

The error occurs when I use the function `scope.toggleOnOff`. For some reason the property "enabled" can not be assigned any longer when project is built.

The selectedProfile is defined in my ctrl:

```
$scope.profiles = InputFactory.getProfiles();
InputFactory.selectedProfile = {
  value: $scope.profiles[0]
};

$scope.selectedProfile = InputFactory.selectedProfile;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And how `selectedProfile.value.slope.enabled` is defined in controller?

Comment: @dfsq I've updated my question.

Comment: Don't know how minification affects your specific app, but check dependencies injected properly in controller.

Comment: Are you using minsafe syntax or using ngAnnotate?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `=` for things that you don't want to assign to.
Use `&` instead, and access that property as a function call inside the directive.

For example, for:

```
columnTitleOne: '&',
```

use it like this in the template:

```
<div>{{columnTitleOne()}}</div>
```

and like this in the directive's javascript code:

```
doSomethingWithTitles($scope.columnTitleOne());
```

As a rule, you should use two-way bindings for stuff you want to assign to That's the reason, I imagine, behind using the `=` to represent it, as a reminder that you should use it if you're going to be doing this somewhere:

```
columnTitleOne = something;
```

If you don't, don't use two-way bindings.